# Equalizer in the category of rings with 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

It is easy to see that in the category $\sf Rng$ of rings, the equalizer of two homomorphisms $f,g\colon R \to S$ is just the inclusion $\ker(f_1-f_2) \hookrightarrow R$. Consider then the category $\sf Ring$ of rings with $1$ and ring homomorphisms mapping $1$ to $1$. Do we still have equalizers in this category? I feel the answer should be no, especially if the morphisms are non-trivial, since then the natural candidate $\ker(f_1-f_2)$ will not be an object of ${\rm Ring}$ (to make it worse, $1 \in \ker(f_1-f_2)$ forces actually $f_1=f_2$).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: $1 \in \ker(f_1-f_2)$ does not force $f_1 = f_2$, because $f_1-f_2$ does not preserve the multiplicative structure, it only preserves the additive structure.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* algebraic category is complete, and the carrier of the limit is the limit of the carriers. Since adding a unit corresponds to adding a constant to the theory of rngs and some equational laws, the category of rings with unit is an algebraic category. The equalizer of two rings is then the equalizer of their carrier sets with the operations restricted to the subset. (You should verify that they are closed.)

Kernels are usually used when a category has a zero object (and thus zero morphisms). This is not the case for $\mathbf{Ring}$. $\mathbf{Ring}$ similarly doesn't admit an abelian group structure on its homsets (i.e. it isn't $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched). At least not in the obvious way. The difference of two (unit preserving) ring homomorphisms isn't a unit preserving ring homomorphism because $(f-g)(1)=f(1)-g(1)=0\neq 1$. Trying to reduce equalizers to kernels doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I am sorry: this went way above my head. E.g., I don't know the meaning of "algebraic category", "carrier", "adding a constant to a theory" (I assume there should be a precise meaning for this). What I agree to is that there is no sense in trying to reduce it to a kernel in $\sf Ring$, but that's exactly what my question is about...

Comment: "Carrier" just means underlying set. The nLab has good articles on algebraic categories, but all that's important here is that for general reasons, $\mathbf{Ring}$ must be complete, and the underlying set of the limit of any ring is the limit of the underlying sets. In other words, if you want to know what the equalizer of rings looks like, just treat the rings as sets (i.e. ignore the operations) and form the equalizer of the sets, i.e. $\{r\in R\mid f(r)=g(r)\}$. That gives you what the elements of the equalizer of rings look like. You then just need to figure out the operations.